# Where does a Field component in Redux form get the input prop from?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

Learning about redux-forms from this [page](http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/docs/api/Field.md/), but don't understand how the input props is given to a Field component like below:

```
class MyCustomInput extends Component {
  render() {
    const { input: { value, onChange } } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <span>The current value is {value}.</span>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => onChange(value + 1)}>Inc</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => onChange(value - 1)}>Dec</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Where is MyCustonInput getting the `input` prop from? The example only shows this below:

```
import MyCustomInput from './MyCustomInput'

...

<Field name="myField" component={MyCustomInput}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Field is a higher order component that applies these properties to whatever is passed in to `component`. It's effectively determining what values the field requires and how it should be connected to the redux store, depending on the component you've passed in and potentially other properties of the `Field`.

The source code is probably the best source of truth on this. You can see where input is defined here in the createFieldProps function:
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/createFieldProps.js